# Cotensoring by a Hopf Algebra

Tags: homological-algebra, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups, hopf-algebras

For $H$ a Hopf algebra, with bijective antipode. For a right, and a left, $H$-comodule $(V,\alpha_R)$, and $(W,\alpha_L)$ respectively, the **cotensor product** of $V$ and $W$ is 
$$
V \square_H W := \ker(\alpha_R \otimes \text{id} - \text{id} \otimes \alpha_L:V \otimes W \to V \otimes H \otimes W).
$$

When does it hold that 
$$
V \square_H H ~~~ \simeq  V? 
$$

Comment: Transferred from Stack Exchange due to no answer .

Comment: Always, and you just need $H$ to be a coalgebra with a counit $\varepsilon$: use the maps $\mathrm{id}\otimes\varepsilon:V\otimes H\to V$ and $\mathrm{id}\otimes\varepsilon:V\otimes H\otimes H\to V\otimes H$ to split the equalizer.

Comment: Can you explain "split the equalizer" please?

Comment: It is a standard abstract nonsense trick, see e. g. in [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/split+equalizer)

Answer (score 1):

For any $H$-comodule $V$ you have its structure map $\rho:V\to V\otimes H$. The image of $\rho$ is the equalizer defining cotensor product.